# Plugin admin panel JavaScript Broken

Tags: admin, plugins, jquery, javascript

I'm trying to implement this plugin on my live wordpress instilation:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/frontpage-slideshow/

I wouldn't usually ask a question about a plugin directly but this problem is a little strange,

I have a local MAMP installation of wordpress running the plugin, everything db and file wise is identical to the live version, taken from my git repository and a up to date dump of the db.

What's very strange here is that the plugin works with no problems on my MAMP instillation, i can access the admin section no problem.

But on my live wordpress instillation, all javascript is broken on the plugins admin page, even the wordpress admin js that controls the menu drop downs.

I'm not sure what is happening as i have 0 js errors in my console and can see exactly the same files are being loaded as on my local instillation.

The only variable here are the servers, but i'm not sure what could be causing this, does anyone have any ideas?

Edit:

I've isolated the problem down to this line:

```
$attachments = get_children(array(
                                    'post_type'     => 'attachment',
                                    'post_mime_type'    => 'image',
                                    'post_status'       => null,
                                    'post_parent'       => null,
                                ));
```

if i remove it everything works fine..

Comment: Sounds wired.  Can you see the if the scripts are loaded in the source code?

Comment: Probably that plugin is overloading the default wordpress script configuration. The forum looks pretty active, have you tried for help there as well? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/frontpage-slideshow/faq/ - if you find a solution you can even answer your own question here later on!

Comment: Try with other plugins disabled... Also confirm if the regular jQuery script is being included in your page(i believe the included scripts will require it, but they don't actually set jQuery as a dependancy when enqueuing). A link to the site would help.. ;)

Comment: Playing around it does indeed look like the plugin is stopping the jQuery script from being included correctly, placing an alert inside a document ready in the footer won't alert, but placing it in the header fires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the null paramaters fixed the problem:

```
$attachments = get_children(array(
    'post_type'     => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type'    => 'image',
));
```